# SQL query to find out other products that a customer purchased with a specific product

Tags: sql, hive

Below is the query that displays the customers who have used the key "3500". But there are other keys in the table.
I am trying to find out what other keys the below customers have used (in addition to 3500).
Would be great for any suggestions !!

```
SELECT distinct(b.id2)
FROM tab1 as a, tab2 as c, tab3 as b
WHERE a.id1 = c.id1 and c.id2 = b.id2
group by b.id2
having count
            (
                case
                    when    key in (3500)
                    then    1
                end
            ) > 0

  id2              key
  123             3500
  123             3501
  123             4100
  234             3500
  234             1234
  234             4100
  312             3500
  312             4100
```

Result: (The above list is only the customers who have used "3500" in combination with other product keys)

```
key(other than 3500)    count
    3501                1
    4100                3
    1234                1
```

Comment: Do you want a list of all the keys that *any* customer has used, or a list of the keys that *each* customer has used, or a count of the number of customers who have used each key?  Or something else?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @rd_nielsen: I want to have the count of customers per key other than the key "3500" (this count is based on the customers who have used "3500")

Comment: Show the structure of your tables, specifically the tables that include the columns for key and customer.

Comment: @rd_nielsen: I have given the structure of table and the result

Comment: @scaisEdge: I have added the sample data. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the structure of the underlying tables, it's not possible to give the most specifically applicable answer, but here's one that should work:

```
with t as (
    SELECT *
    FROM
        tab1 as a
        INNER JOIN tab2 as c ON c.id1=a.id1
        INNER JOIN tab3 as b ON b.id2=c.id2
    ),
custkeys as (
    select distinct id2, key
    from t
    ),
cust3500 as (
    select distinct id2
    from custkeys
    where key = 3500
    )
select
    key,
    count(*) as customers
from
    custkeys as k
    inner join cust3500 as c on c.id2=k.id2
where
    key <> 3500;
```

The `custkeys` CTE might be unnecessary, or might be replaced with something simpler, and the `cust3500` CTE might also be altered, depending on the actual structure of your tables.